# can I check the gtest_filter from inside a non-gtest test?

Tags: c++, continuous-integration, googletest, qtestlib

I have a test suite written in `QTestLib`.  That's legacy.  The `QTest` tests are invoked from a `main` method initialized like a regular gtest suite.

On the CI server we invoke regular gtests with a 'time sensitive exclusion' filter like

```
> testsuite.exe --gtest_filter=-*TimeSensitive*
```

Now I would like to try disabling some of these time sensitive tests by 'listening' to the `gtest_filter`.  So the question: can I use something equivalent to this?

```
MyTest::test_TimeSensitiveTestMethod() {
    if (!::testing::gtest_filter("MyTest_TimeSensitiveTestMethod")) return;
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 2);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually solved the problem by merely wrapping the qtests into gtests:

```
TEST(MyGtestWrapper, theQtest_TimeSensitive) {
    MyTest test;
    ASSERT_NE(QTEST_FAILED, QTest::exec(&test, 0, 0));
}
```

The test `main` has to instantiate a `QApplication` and `exec` it, of course.